# Validation test evaluates BigDecimal 0.0 to null

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.4.3

I have a property named value of type BigDecimal which is defined like this:

```
@BindUsing({ obj, source ->
  if (source['value']) {
        source['value']?.toBigDecimal()
    } else {
        null
    }
})
BigDecimal value
```

Now if I use this value in a constraint, I get the following strange behaviour:

```
if (obj.value)
```

evaluates to false if value is set to 0.0
It evaluates to true for any other value (e.g. 0.1)

0.0 is actually stored as 0.0 in the database table, but the validator obviously thinks it is null.

Or is there maybe a problem using "value" as the name for a property?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is how Groovy evaluates truth. The [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth) has the following example:

```
assert !0 //yeah, 0s are false, like in Perl
assert 1  //this is also true for all other number types
```

Numbers, 0.0 in your case, evaluate to false when they are zero. If you are trying to check for null values, then you should be checking for null values in this case.

```
if (obj.value == null)
```